# Load, modify, and write an XML document in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an XML document that I want to load from a file, modify a few specific elements, and then write back to disk.

I can't find any examples of how to do this in Groovy.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just modify the node's **value** property to modify the values of elements.

```
/* input:
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar id="test">
      test
    </bar>
    <baz id="test">
      test
    </baz>
  </foo>
</root>
*/

def xmlFile = "/tmp/test.xml"
def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
xml.foo[0].each { 
    it.@id = "test2"
    it.value = "test2"
}
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).print(xml)

/* output:
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar id="test2">
      test2
    </bar>
    <baz id="test2">
      test2
    </baz>
  </foo>
</root>
*/
```

Comment: This works but will mess up the formatting in your file and delete all comments. Here's an alternative that preserves formatting and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690526/preserve-formatting-when-updating-xml-file-with-groovy#answer-20720694

Comment: You can also preserve the format by simply pulling `new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile)))` into a variable `nodePrinter` and setting `nodePrinter.preserveWhitespace = true` before calling `print(xml)`

Comment: For me output file is empty

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html):

```
//Open file
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse('/tmp/file.xml')

//Edit File e.g. append an element called foo with attribute bar
xml.appendNode {
   foo(bar: "bar value")
}

//Save File
def writer = new FileWriter('/tmp/file.xml')

//Option 1: Write XML all on one line
def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
writer << builder.bind {
  mkp.yield xml
}

//Option 2: Pretty print XML
XmlUtil.serialize(xml, writer)
```

Note:
`XmlUtil` can also be used with the `XmlParser` as used in @John Wagenleitner's example.

References:

- [Option 1](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/how-to-save-as-XML-after-reading-XML-with-XmlSlurper-td1351877.html)
- [Option 2](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/10/groovy-goodness-pretty-print-xml.html)

Comment: I got a similar issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629223/how-to-add-an-attribute-which-contains-colonfor-xml-element-and-then-serializ).Could you help me?It's consuming my 2 days time.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty exhaustive set of examples for reading/writing XML using Groovy [here](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html). Regarding the loading/saving the data to/from a file, the various methods/properties that Groovy adds to `java.io.File`, should provide the functionality you need. Examples include:

```
File.write(text)
File.text
File.withWriter(Closure closure)
```

See [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) for a complete list of these methods/properties.

Comment: @Gangnus Thanks for the constructive criticism.

Comment: But you really haven't said WHAT functionality he needs.

Answer (score 0):

For the one who find the output empty, here is the solution:

```
def xml = file("${projectDir}/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(file(xml))
manifest.@package = "com.newapp.id"
xml.withWriter {out->
    XmlUtil.serialize(manifest, out)
}
```