# How to edit vsixmanifest using groovy without loosing content?

Tags: gradle, groovy

My question may sound stupid but I am struggling to achieve my result. I would like to edit and save version tage of vsixmanifest file without loosing any content. This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568442/update-xml-elements-with-specific-id-in-gradle) almost solved my purpose but it removes some of the tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
  <Identifier Id="Visual Test">
    <Name>Visual Gallery Test</Name>
    <Author>Visual Studio Demo</Author>
    <Version>XXXXX</Version>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Visual Studio Gallery Demo</Description>
    <Locale>1033</Locale>
    <AllUsers>true</AllUsers>
    <InstalledByMsi>false</InstalledByMsi>
    <Icon>Resources/Icon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>Resources/Preview.png</PreviewImage>
    <SupportedProducts>
      <IsolatedShell Version="7.0">Visual Studio</IsolatedShell>
    </SupportedProducts>
    <SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.6" MaxVersion="4.9" />
  </Identifier>
  <Content>
    <VsPackage>XX.pkgdef</VsPackage>
  </Content>
</Vsix>
```

Here is my gradle script

```
task updateExtensionManifest{
    def vsixmanifestFile = "build/source.extension.vsixmanifest"
    def vsixmanifest = new XmlParser().parse(vsixmanifestFile)
    vsixmanifest.Identifier[0].Version[0].value="YYYYY"
    def nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(vsixmanifestFile)))
    nodePrinter.preserveWhitespace = true
    nodePrinter.expandEmptyElements = true
    nodePrinter.print(vsixmanifest)
}
```

When I execute the script it removes some of the tags defines manifest file, this is how it looks after task is getting executed:

```
<Vsix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010" Version="1.0.0">
  <Identifier Id="Visual Test">
    <Name>Visual Gallery Test</Name>
    <Author>Visual Studio Demo</Author>
    <Version>YYYYY</Version>
    <Description xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">Visual Studio Gallery Demo</Description>
    <Locale>1033</Locale>
    <AllUsers>true</AllUsers>
    <InstalledByMsi>false</InstalledByMsi>
    <Icon>Resources/Icon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>Resources/Preview.png</PreviewImage>
    <SupportedProducts>
      <IsolatedShell Version="7.0">Visual Studio</IsolatedShell>
    </SupportedProducts>
    <SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.6" MaxVersion="4.9"></SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition>
  </Identifier>
  <Content>
    <VsPackage>XX.pkgdef</VsPackage>
  </Content>
</Vsix>
```

Some unwanted edits:

```
Line1 removed: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Line2 modified to <Vsix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010" Version="1.0.0">
Tag "Description" got edited too..
```

How could I avoid this edits? I just expected the version to get modified from XXXXX to YYYYY without changing any other content through my gradle build script.

Comment: But the output generate is very much valid. Are you facing any error while using the same later?

Comment: No I am not facing any error, but not able to understand why lines are getting removed/edited.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `XmlNodePrinter`.

If `xml` markup declaration is needed, use `XmlUtil.serialize()`.

```
def vsixmanifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(vsixmanifestFile)
vsixmanifest.Identifier[0].Version.replaceBody ( "YYYYY" )
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(vsixmanifest)
```

You can quickly try the [demo](https://ideone.com/Ur5cSS)