# Parsing section of XML file

Tags: xml, groovy

My xml is like this:

```
<rootnode>
   <child name="tony">
   ...
   </child>
   <child name="antho">
   ...
   </child>
</rootnode>
```

I want to be able to output the xml element for child tony verbatim. 
I can find this element using XmlSlurper but then I am left with an object represent, I just want the XML verbatim.  How do I do that?

```
   <child name="tony">
   ...
   </child>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer to this question:
[Load, modify, and write an XML document in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245641/load-modify-and-write-an-xml-document-in-groovy)

In short, it seems the simple solution is to read xml with `XmlSlurper` and write with `XmlUtil`:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlString)
def prettyXmlNode = XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```