# Parsing xml file at build time and modify its values/content

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to parse a xml file during build time in `build.gradle` file and want to modify some values of xml, i follow this SO question and answer [Load, modify, and write an XML document in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245641/load-modify-and-write-an-xml-document-in-groovy) but not able to get any change in my xml file. can anyone help me out. Thanks

code in `build.gradle` :

```
def overrideLocalyticsValues(String token) {
def xmlFile = "/path_to_file_saved_in_values/file.xml"
def locXml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)

locXml.resources[0].each {
    it.@ll_app_key = "ll_app_key"
    it.value = "123456"
}
XmlNodePrinter nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile)))
nodePrinter.preserveWhitespace = true
nodePrinter.print(locXml)
}
```

xml file :

```
<resources>
<string name="ll_app_key" translatable="false">MY_APP_KEY</string>
<string name="ll_gcm_sender_id" translatable="false">MY_GCM_SENDER_ID</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code : Is it right ...? Where is node name and attribute ..?

```
locXml.resources[0].each {    // Wrongly entered without node name 
    it.@ll_app_key = "ll_app_key"   // Attribute name @name
    it.value = "123456"           // you can't change or load values here
}
```

You tried to read and write a same file. Try this code which replaces the exact node of the xml file. `XmlSlurper` provides this facility.

Updated :

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xmlFile = "test.xml"
def locXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)


locXml.'**'.findAll{ if (it.name() == 'string' && it.@name == "ll_app_key") it.replaceBody 12345 }

new File (xmlFile).text = XmlUtil.serialize(locXml)
```

Comment: Getting this error regarding XmlUtil: Error:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'XmlUtil' on project ':app'.

Comment: @KapilRajput you don't need XmlUtil you can remove it. check with my updated ans.

Comment: thanks i can see the changes in gradle console but can you please suggest me how to override these changes in actual file saved in values folder

Comment: @KapilRajput Can you  `import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder` ..? if can't, you need to have `grooovy-xml` jar.

Comment: `def writer = new FileWriter(xmlFile)
XmlUtil.serialize(locXml,writer)` works please edit your answer may helps someone also

Comment: @KapilRajput You said `XmlUtil ` not working ... right? If it does you can use one line code to modify file as per my updated answer ...

Comment: it works by importing `import groovy.xml.*` in gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Groovy has a better method for this than basic replacement like you're trying to do - the [SimpleTemplateEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html)

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    def templateEngine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
    def template = '<someXml>${someValue}</someXml>'
    def templateArgs = [someValue: "Hello world!"]
    println templateEngine.createTemplate(template).make(templateArgs).toString()
}
```

Output:

`<someXml>Hello world!</someXml>`