# How to modify xml elements from an xml file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an issue with my pipeline. I have an XML file in my project repo and I will like to read this file and change values after my checkout stage.

verNum.xml

```
<Version>1.0.0 </Version>
```

and my jenkinsfile

```
node {
    stage ('checkout') {
    .......
    }
    stage ('readfile') {
        readFile("verNum.xml")
    }
}
```

I would increment the last digit of the version number with my build number. say something like this `1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}`.

Your help is highly welcomed.

Comment: You should be able to modify [this groovy example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245641/load-modify-and-write-an-xml-document-in-groovy) to use readfile and writefile

Comment: what are you using for building? mvn? gradle? anything else? Normally this is part of the packaging process where you actually give the version number as parameter.

Comment: @hakamairi  I am using dotnet. I know this can be done using the -p flag to increment version number in project files.However, i want to use a different approach to that by first reading this xml file where the version number is stated, and replace this version number with the version number in my .csproj file

Comment: Hmm.. may I suggest you to reconsider -p flag ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use linux cmd: `sed` to replace text.

```
sh '''
   sed -r -i 's/(<Version>1.0.)[0-9]*(.*)/\\1'$BUILD_NUMBER'\\2/' verNum.xml
'''
```

Comment: i tried this command but i got an error saying unexpected char: ' \ '

Comment: @Leroi I am getting the same error - could you please tell me how did you resolve this?